# JSP - How can I send data and recieve a response when sending to an external site

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, http, servlets

I have a problem. I need to be able to perform a send in my JSP, which is running in a Spring and JBOSS environment. The problem is the data needs to be sent to an external site. This site needs to be able to receive the data, perform processing and they need to provide a mechanism to provide a response back to the calling JSP.

I have tried this with AJAX post, but there is an issue with the cross site scripting

I have also tried doing an AJAX post to the app server, then the app server servlet does a HTTP post to the external site.

But I need a way to send this to the external site from the browser.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: If you want to do this from the browser, this is neither ar java nor a servlets issue. And, first of all, since it looks like you don't control the server you want to connect to, you should get sure that it allows for this kind of behavior.

Comment: what's wrong with posting a regular form?

Comment: But how do I get the response back to the JSP from a reg. form post?

Answer (score 1):

You **can** do cross domain requests, as you manage yourself the called server.

Simply set the proper headers on the called server :

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
```

Note that you may set something more specific than `*`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

**EDIT :** I'm not sure I understood the question, this is only useful if you can change the "external" server. Is that the case ?